# Earth, Sun and beginner's reference frames

Tags: reference-frames, definition, inertial-frames, celestial-mechanics

In the post-Newton era, where "absolute space" is not absolute,
how is the reference frame in which "the Earth moves round the Sun" 
accurately defined?

Answer (score 1):

Rotation *is* absolute. And in any non-rotating reference frame, the earth and the sun (ignoring all the other bodies in the solar system, and the rest of the universe) both revolve around their common center of mass. Since the mass of the sun is so much greater than the mass of the earth, it is pretty close to saying that the sun is stationary and the earth orbits around it, since the center of mass of the earth-sun system is pretty close to the center of the sun.

That remains true no matter what non-rotating reference frame you are in - the sun and the earth both revolve about their common center of mass, and the different reference frames just amount to different views of how the center of mass is moving relative to the observer.

Comment: at PhillS: Is there a theorem involved in giving such priority 
to the center of mass?
In a setting where a large mass rotates round a small one,
taking the center of mass as reference-frame
would show the small mass rotating round the large.

Comment: A large mass doesn't ever revolve around a small one if we are just talking about two bodies moving under their gravitational attraction. This is a direct consequence of Newton's law of gravity $F=\frac{GM_1M_2}{r^2}$ : the solutions of the orbits for a two-body problem have them both orbiting the center of mass. This is a standard result that outght to be covered in many textbooks and web pages (such as on wikipedia). Incidentally, rotate = spinning on its own axis, revolve = orbit around something.

Comment: at PhillS: But what if, in a many-bodies setting, a large mass does revolve
round a small one? Is there a theorem about this being impossible?